# I ate sehri and made the Dua but there was time before sehri and ate it again

Tags: hadith

I ate sehri and made Dua but after some time I ate again but there was time in adhan is it ok

Answer (score 1):

It is fine to eat as many times as you wish within the time of sehri, even if you recited the dua for closing the fast after each time, because the permissibility of eating before the [time of fajr](https://islamicknowledges.com/what-is-ramadan-importance-of-ramadan-in-islam/) starting is established from the Quran:

وَكُلُوۡا وَاشۡرَبُوۡا حَتّٰى يَتَبَيَّنَ لَـكُمُ الۡخَـيۡطُ الۡاَبۡيَضُ مِنَ الۡخَـيۡطِ الۡاَسۡوَدِ مِنَ الۡفَجۡرِ

‘And eat and drink until the white thread becometh distinct to you from the black thread of the dawn.’

[Surah al-Baqarah, Verse 187]

In addition, reciting the dua is in reality making intention to close the fast. Also, the jurists have stated that if one had made the intention for closing the fast in the night, even then it is fine for him to consume food and drink within the sehri time.

Just as it is stated in [Bahar-e-Shariat](https://www.seekerspath.co.uk/question-bank/fasting/q-id0791-i-recited-the-dua-to-close-my-fast-but-there-is-some-time-left-till-fajr-starts-can-i-still-eat-and-drink/),

‘If he made an intention in the night, and then later on, in the same night, he ate and drank, the intention does not become invalid, rather, the initial intention is sufficient; it is not necessary to make an intention again.’

[Bahar-e-Shariat, vol. 1, part 5, pg. 969]